# DatePicker on a textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am trying to implement a `datepicker` control using Jquery,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jqueryrelese.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>").datepicker();

        });

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

but it is not working as `datepicker` doesn't popup. What code i am missing or any is there any error in this code. Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Try typing `console.log(...)` and see result in Chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {

            $("#"+'<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>').datepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And make sure that you have included all required .js files on your page.
For Ex: If you are using [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) Jquery Datepicker you must include:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:**
You will get these .js files [here](http://jqueryui.com/download) along with demo.

Comment: have you checked the .js files you included on your page contains a method for "datepicker". Check this Demo Project (http://www.filedropper.com/webapplication2) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Sir for the project basically i was doing error in including the Jquery Files, now its working.

Answer (score 7):

### Place jquery script reference before jquery-ui.

By the way, since this is asp.net code, use this id selectors: `$("#<%= Textbox1.ClientID %>").datepicker();` for server controls as client id may be changed by asp.net infrastructure